# How to get a HTML element loaded w Javascript using Powershell? Code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, powershell, web-crawler

I expected the Powershell code bellow to get a HTML element by class, but the result is `$null`, while expected it to return the text `My Class`.

The HTML page was deployed and published as Google Web App by me, but Google uses Javascript to load my HTLM code, so how can I get a HTML element loaded with Javascript using Powershell? (I cannot use Google APIs)

Powershell:

```
$url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyxP3Gjvy50oCwLoAB2vuWWgcA75MJ0vIgf9GiQCkNzxb5QGNE/exec' 
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url 
$feedback = $response.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByClassName("note") | select -expand innertext
write-host "feedback: " $feedback
```

Comment: There's not class `note` on that page.

Comment: @JackFleeting, if you select the line, right-click on it and select "inspect", you'll see the line `<span class="note">my class</span>`

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the element is loaded with javascript; don't think powershell can handle that.

Comment: Due to Google's use of secure nested iframe sandboxing (and warden JS event handler enforcement), you may not be able to reliably retrieve the rendered HTML using this technique.  Same origin script access (from google.com) may be the only secure way to retrieve it, and avoid "access denied" messages from secure clients that prevent cross-site scripting.